# If statment only checks one time

Tags: java, android, if-statement, button, android-edittext

I want my `btnsave` to work only when there is something in `editText`.
First, when application launched, when there is not anything in `editText` my code works (`btnsave` does not work). But when i type something in `editText` I expect `btnsave` to be able to work. But no! It doesn't work. I think if statement only runs one time.

What is the problem?
I want this code run permanently while the application is running.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    if (!editText.getText().toString().matches(""))
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"H", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

}
```

In other words

```
btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

if (editText.getText().toString().matches(""))
    btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
else
    btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
```

When app launchs , btn is disabled(because `editText` is empty ) but when i type a text in `editText`it is expected that btn gets enabled but it doesnt!

i think when i type sth in `editText` it doesnt recheck the conditions .WHY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0)  {
                    btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: yes it works but i didnt mean that.my question is :for example,i want a button to be enable when i type sth in editText and when i remove what i typed in editText i want the button get disabled.my question is how to code this?

Comment: Try EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    Button.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    Button.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }});

Comment: Attach this listener to your edit text according to your edittext name.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the following logic:

1. Create & implement the onClickListener.
2. Specify the conditional statement.
3. Execute the action.

The following snippet should meet your needs:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(newView.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
    if(!editText.getText().toString().matches("")){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "H", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

If you want to make your button usable when there's text in the EditText and not when there's none, you can use the following property:

```
btn.setClickable(true);
```

Just use this line in the conditional statement.

Comment: yes it works but i didnt mean that.my question is :for example,i want a button to be enable when i type sth in editText and when i remove what i typed in editText i want the button get disabled.my question is how to code this?

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Check the snippet with the changes.